# magento admin - newsletter template

Tags: magento, templates, admin, newsletter

How much length does my html code have to be , while creating newsletter template. Because while saving , some of the code are disappeared from the end 
P.S: Is there any code length limit in newsletter template? If yes , then how to increase the length.

Comment: Are you using the WYSIWYG editor? This can strip out code when you save.

Comment: yes , I'm using WYSIWYG editor. Is there any other way to overcome this issue?

Comment: The editor will cause you all sorts of problems if you're adding HTML, CSS or JS. I can only advise not using it or developing outside Magento and pasting in with WYSIWYG turned off.